# How to use multiple payment gateways function in single controller in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, paypal, controller, laravel-8, payment-gateway

I am using PayPal, Razor pay, Stripe payment gateways in my project. When select user one of them payment gateway it redirects to assigned controller function from there it redirects its particular controller. I want to write all the functions for payment gateways in single controller to cut off redirections for  customer.

[image]

when user select payment gateway and submit the form it redirects to mentioned below controller function

```
 if ($payment_mode->payment_gateway_name == "Paypal") {
                return redirect()->route('paywithpaypal', $planId);
            } else if ($payment_mode->payment_gateway_name == "Razorpay") {
                return redirect()->route('paywithrazorpay', $planId);
            } else if ($payment_mode->payment_gateway_name == "Stripe") {
                return redirect()->route('paywithstripe', $planId);
            } else if ($payment_mode->payment_gateway_name == "Bank Transfer") {
    }
```

and in that controller all functions is defined.

Comment: No offence, but I think it’s probably out of your scope because you’re actually asking the question, but you could subclass the Illuminate/Support/Manager class with a payment gateway and then create the different gateway classes as drivers (https://pineco.de/drivers-and-managers-in-laravel/) that way you could write one function in your controller which would handle all instances of your payment gateway.

Comment: @savlon exact code I needed for modification as i am beginner to laravel

Comment: Exactly my point lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Classes as below:

1. PaymentController
2. Seperate classes implementing RazorpayService, StripeService, BankTransferService apis
3. Factory Method to create class object of RazorpayService, StripeService, BankTransferService based on request parameters

PaymentController uses factory method to create object of appropriate service and calls appropriate method on this object using input parameters

Comment: separate class or function?

Comment: just one example can you give me by coding?

Comment: I dont have source code for your problem, but Strategy Pattren is what you are looking for. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy/php